# How to print report on client side printer using ASPxDocumentViewer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

We are working on 14.1.7 version of Devexpress. We have an application running on a server. This server is not in our local network. 
Our project is preparing reports to print after some operation on each cleints  in different network area.Think one our customer (client) in USA,
another is in Russia. But they want to use their loacal printer to print report. And we succesfully print report in development enviroment in visiual st 2010 until publish on remote server.
Additionly we add data to report as dynimically. And we get error "No printers are installed".

Thanks for helps....

Comment: can you provide more details and code which having problem? which method you are using to print report with document viewer?? it will be hard to know the what issue you are facing with such description.

Comment: it may be possible  client system does not have any printer installed on the system. In that case this error is correct.